# Displaying Pagination in posts in new theme

Tags: wordpress, post, pagination

I am developing Custom Theme and I want to display pagination in `blog` page.

**Here's the `wp_query`:**

```
    <?php
        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
            $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 2,
            'paged'          => $paged
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); 
    ?>
```

**The Code to display `Title` and `Excerpt`: and `endwhile` loop**

```
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><div class="titleline"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></div></a>

        <li><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?></li>
    <?php 
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

**And the `Pagination` Starts Here:**

```
<div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>
<div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;') ?></div>
```

***Am I missing anything here? Any suggestion will be appreciated..***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your template file

```
<?php
global $query_string;
                                query_posts($query_string . "post_type=post&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=2");  
                                if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                                <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                                 <h5>Posted By :  <?php the_author(); ?> | Date : <?php echo the_date('d-m-y'); ?></h5>
                                <p><?php  the_excerpt(); ?></p>

                            <?php endwhile;
                                endif; ?>
                                <?php pagination_numeric_posts_nav(); ?>
                        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

And put this function in functions.php file of theme

```
function pagination_numeric_posts_nav() {

    if( is_singular() )
        return;

    global $wp_query;

    /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
    if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return;

    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

    /** Add current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 1 )
        $links[] = $paged;

    /** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }

    if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }

    echo '<div class=""><ul class="pagination">' . "\n";

    /** Previous Post Link */
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link() );

    /** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>';
    }

    /** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
    sort( $links );
    foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
    }

    /** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

        $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
    }

    /** Next Post Link */
    if ( get_next_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link() );

    echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";

}
```

add this css in your style.css file

```
.navigation li a,
.navigation li a:hover,
.navigation li.active a,
.navigation li.disabled {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.navigation li {
    display: inline;
}

.navigation li a,
.navigation li a:hover,
.navigation li.active a,
.navigation li.disabled {
    background-color: #6FB7E9;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 12px;
    padding: 0.75rem;
}

.navigation li a:hover,
.navigation li.active a {
    background-color: #3C8DC5;
}
```

And check your reading setting
[image]

Change query_posts parameter if your blog page is not your static front page

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('posts_per_page'=>2,'paged'=>$paged);

query_posts($args);
```

Comment: the above code did nothing. It even didn't displayed the contents and titles of the posts

Comment: can you please elaborate your problem. Please provide complete description of the issue you are facing. it's working fine for me

Comment: the issue is i want to show pagination in my custom theme. I copied your code exactly in my `template` file and `functions.php` file  but showed nothing

Comment: <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?> just simply put this code in your template file and check it's working fine or not. and please check how many publish post you have.

Comment: i have total of 3 . with my above code it shows the posts. if i change it to `per_page=2` it shows 2 posts and if 3 , it shows 3 posts. I just want to display pagination that's it .. :)

Comment: put your code in template file and add pagination function <?php wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav(); ?> afer endwhile;

Comment: well that's different function. can you try my code and add pagination in your theme file ? and let me know ?

Comment: I have test with your code and modify some of code. code look like this.     <?php
       global $query_string;
        query_posts($query_string . "post_type=post&posts_per_page=2");
        if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><div class="titleline"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></div></a>
 <li><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?></li>
    <?php 
        endwhile;
  endif;
   wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav(); 
  wp_reset_postdata();
    ?> it's working fine for me.

Comment: `wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav` this function is from wpbeginner.com we haven't defined any function anywhere bro

Comment: I get your problem .. i have set static home page and put this code in this template file. i think you don't do this

Comment: $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('posts_per_page'=>2,'paged'=>$paged);
query_posts($args);  change this  in my code

Comment: can you edit your previous `code` with this `code` again please/

Comment: I have modify my post and add this line of code in bottom. just simply replace query_posts parameter. for your reference just remove this line from my old code query_posts($query_string . "post_type=post&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=2");   and add  new query_posts parameter. $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('posts_per_page'=>2,'paged'=>$paged);
query_posts($args);

Comment: thanx , finally worked with this code
`$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('posts_per_page'=>2,'paged'=>$paged);

query_posts($args);`